# UIView Animation with duration causing Bad Access Issue

Tags: ios, core-animation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using completion with animateWithDuration causes exc_bad_access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957826/using-completion-with-animatewithduration-causes-exc-bad-access)

I am really confused here.

The following code works fine

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f 
    animations:^{
        flipView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    } 
    completion:nil 
];
```

but this causes a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
    animations:^{
        flipView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {} 
 ];
```

Any idea why this would be? I have tried creating a new project with just a view and the same issue is happening.

Comment: i dont want to seem mean or anything but with the console error and 5 min or search i found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957826/using-completion-with-animatewithduration-causes-exc-bad-access) :) . Same problem as you.

Comment: I saw that earlier and tried it and it did not work. Went to double check now and realized I only removed it from the project and not the Target build settings. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

well insert something in the parentheses after `(BOOL finished)` because after the animation is over the method is trying to execute completion block..and doesn't find anything there to do..and it crashes

that's why it works with `nil` ..cuz it knows there is nothing more to do

Comment: Even when I try  

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^{flipView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2,1.0,0.0,0.0);} completion:^(BOOL finished){ NSLog(@"DONE");} ];

It still crashes. I have used this code before and worked fine, I think I may be stumbling across something really peculiar.

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: All it says is EXEC_BAD_ACCESS code=2